# void value not ignored as it ought to be. Setting reference to pointer member by method from iterator

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, iterator

If I call `SetCFoo` from ccfoo it works, but from iterator (in loop) it doesn't.

```
class CFoo{};

class CCFoo
{
public:
    CFoo *m_cf;
    void SetCFoo(CFoo *cf)
    {
        m_cf = cf;
    }
};

int main()
{
    CCFoo ccfoo;
    CFoo cfoo;

    //ccfoo.SetCFoo(&cfoo);  <-- It works

    vector<CCFoo> v1;
    v1.assign(5,*new CCFoo); // I don't care about leak because it is example

    for(vector<CCFoo>::iterator it = v1.begin(); it != v1.end(); it++ )
    {
        *it->SetCFoo(&cfoo);
    }
}
```

Compiler give me following error:
*void value not ignored as it ought to be*

Comment: Try `it->SetCFoo(&cfoo);`

Comment: How doesn't it work? If the compiler gives you an error message you need to **edit your post** and include it. If it's a runtime error we need to know that too.

Comment: Ok. Error was included in topic.

Comment: I highly doubt the compiler issued the error _"void value not ignored as it ought to be"_. ;p

Comment: Yes, it was. gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*it->SetCFoo(&cfoo);
```

is the same as

```
*(it->SetCFoo(&cfoo));
```

What you need is:

```
(*it).SetCFoo(&cfoo);
```

or just

```
it->SetCFoo(&cfoo);
```

The `*` at the start of the statement is not only not needed but it causes the compiler error since you can't apply the unary `*` operator on the returned value of `CCFoo::SetCFoo()`, which is of type `void`.

Comment: Maybe `(*it).SetCFoo(&cfoo);` ?

Comment: Ugh. Just state it: `it->SetCFoo(...)`. The `*` is completely extraneous. No need to be (*awkward)